# How to test a PDO::execute() failure

Tags: php, pdo, phpunit

I'm using PDO and PHPUnit for a professionnal project.

Here is the method, in my codebase, I want to test :

```
public function signUp(\PDO $pdo) 
{
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO user VALUES (
        DEFAULT, 
        :firstName, 
        :lastName,
        :salutation,
        :birthday,
        :email,
        :password
    )");

    $statement->bindValue(':firstName', $this->firstName);
    $statement->bindValue(':lastName', $this->lastName);
    // Etc...

    if($statement->execute()) {
        $this->id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        return $this->id;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to find a way that my `$statement->execute()` fails and return `false` according to the [PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.execute.php)

And the test method, I would like to implement :

```
testSignupInsertRowFailAndReturnZeroValue()
```

Does that make sense to test this ?

---

EDIT

Here is a solution with a simple Mock :

```
$pdoMock = $this->getMockBuilder('PDO')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

    $pdoMock->method("prepare")
            ->will($this->returnValue(new \PDOStatement()));
```

Comment: use try/catch exception handling maybe ?

Comment: [Mock your PDO object](http://erichogue.ca/2013/02/best-practices/mocking-pdo-in-phpunit/) to return a mocked statement object?

Comment: Yep thanks good idea. I'll edit my question with my implementation. Is this what you mean ?

Comment: Something along those lines, though you'd also need to create a mock of the PDOStatement on the prepare() as well, so you could control the return from execute()

Answer (score 0):

`execute` returns `true` on success and `false` on failure as per the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

If I understand your question correctly, you could check if your query failed with something like:

```
if($statement->execute()) {
  // success
}
else{
  // failure
}
```

Comment: Yes but my question is not about implementation. It's about writing a test, that trigger a non successful case and assert that it's a fail.